# Python module not working if called from main?

Tags: python, module, python-requests

I have a project going. In the project folder, I have another folder (lib) and inside that folder I have 2 files. The contents of each is below. The problem is that req.py runs perfectly by itself, but when I run main.py, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\redacted\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    req.req()
  File "C:\Users\redacted\lib\req.py", line 13, in req
    return r.content
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 595, in content
    content = decode_gzip(self._content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 354, in decode_gzip
    return zlib.decompress(content, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not None
```

Setup below:
`__init__.py:import req`

main.py

```
import lib as n
if __name__ == "__main__":
    req = n.req.req()
    req.req()
```

req.py

```
import requests

class req():
    def __init__(self):
        ua     = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2'
        self.w = requests.session( headers = { 'User-Agent': ua } )

    def req(self):
        r = self.w.get('http://www.google.com')
        return r.content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = req()
    print r.req()
```

I am entirely out of ideas. Is there any explanation for what's causing this?

Comment: Show ALL of the traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: What is the requests module and where can we find it?

Comment: Added full traceback.
Requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Just a hint. This traceback is caused by an `AttributeError` in lines 583-587 of [requests/models.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/develop/requests/models.py).

Comment: @yak, that's irrelevant because the fact remains that it works perfectly when I run req.py. My question, I suppose, is the difference between using the req class from main.py and using it from req.py.

Answer (score 0):

> In the project folder, I have another folder (lib) and inside that
>   folder I have 2 files.

Should be 3.

> Setup below:
>   __init__.py:import req

Is this 3rd file or?

Comment: Why should it be three? /project/main.py, /project/lib/__init__.py, /project/lib/req.py.

Comment: Ok than, I recreated all of the files and everything run fine. There **must** be something wrong with unshown parts of the code.

Comment: There are no unshown parts. That's my exact setup. I duplicated the issue with this file setup.

Comment: Would it help if I mentioned that I have a problem importing json from certain folders? Seemingly random errors based on the folder I'm in. It also happens from within python console.

Comment: Did you try to remove projects .pyc files?

Comment: Should be your OS problem, have you another system running capable of testing (worked for me both Debian/python2.7 and win32/python2.5)? Or just another python (2.6 maybe) installed to try with it (you should install **requests** with c:\Python26\Scrypts\easy_install)?

Comment: I installed requests with pip (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), but I don't have another system for testing right now. I'll install Debian (I've been missing it anyway) in VM and try there. Thanks. Also, I'm on the windows developer preview. Thanks.